# enable URL rewrite module on iis

Tags: .net, iis-7.5

I want to add a redirect rule on site but I cannot find rewrite URL module in site under iis.
does anyone know how to enable the urlrewrite module in iis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLRewrite module for IIS is an addon. It is not preinstalled.
That's why you actually cannot find it.

You can download if from here:

x86: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9722533
x64: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9722532

It only works on IIS 7+.

Here is the good [How-To tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). The best one I could find in several hours.

That's a [configuration reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

Here is a one another tool which helped my to understand this module:
http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com/
It lets you convert any `.htaccess` file to `Web.config`.